# How do I change the prompt color of Anaconda Prompt (cmd) on Windows 10?

Tags: cmd, anaconda, command-prompt

I've been trying to change the color of Anaconda Prompts(cmd), which is for now `(base) E:\VSCodeProjects>`.

I googled for this extensively but seems like:

1. There is no such option to do this in `.condarc`. I expected it to be able to change the prompt color like `.zshrc`.
2. Also, I can't find any definitive way to change the color of the prompt of native Windows' cmd. All I found were [some old ANSI Escape codes someone wrote back in 2009](https://gynvael.coldwind.pl/?id=188&lang=en).
3. The only viable and reliable way I came across is setting the `%PROMPT%` variable on terminal manually, by doing something like: `set "PROMPT=$e[44m%PROMPT%$e[0m"`. This command explicitly change the color of the prompt instantly without any side-effects but the problem is that I have to execute this command everytime I open the new Anaconda Prompt instance.

At this point, it would be satisfactory enough if there's a way to just execute `set "PROMPT=$e[44m%PROMPT%$e[0m"` command everytime I open a new Anaconda Prompt instance. However, other more effective approaches are welcome.

Please note that **I'm NOT trying to change the color of the whole Anaconda Prompt. I just want to change the color of the prompt. i.e, `(base) E:\VSCodeProjects>`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realise this is an old post, but thought I'd respond in case anyone is still looking for an answer. If you right click on the top of the Anaconda Prompt window and then click 'properties' on the pop-up, you are able to access all the customisation options.

[image: Screenshot of method explained above]

Comment: This seems to change all the font color, not only the prompt such as `(base)C:\Users\myname>`. But I still appreciate you leaving the answer :)